# xslt issue after converting html to xslt with <script> tag

Tags: html, xslt

I am converting html to xslt and in my html I am having two  tag like this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="slider/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" jquery.mobile, carousel></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slider/js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.js" jquery.mobile, carousel></script>
```

But if i convert html from xslt and in my xslt same thing will be there right but this is giving error on this line. So please let me know how to solve this issue.
Error in xslt when opening in browser is shown below

**This page contains the following errors:
error on line 12 at column 30: Specification mandate value for attribute jquery.mobile
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**

Comment: What is the `jquery.mobile, carousel` string in the `<script>` tag for? It seems to be making the parse choke.

Answer (score 0):

Well an XSLT stylesheet needs to be a namespace well-formed XML document. The syntax `<script type='text/javascript' src="slider/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" jquery.mobile, carousel></script>` is not XML syntax so you can't use that within an XSLT stylesheet. I am not sure what purpose that syntax would have with HTML either so I can't suggest how to achieve its purpose with proper XML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**An XSLT stylesheet must be a well-formed XML document**.

The provided text:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="slider/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" jquery.mobile, carousel></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="slider/js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.js" jquery.mobile, carousel></script>
```

isn't a well-formed XML fragment (there is text after the `src` attribute, which isn't allowed within an XML element), therefore its inclusion into an XSLT stylesheet makes the whole stylesheet non-well-formed XML document.